# TCP connect() (in C) always fails, even when the server is telnet accessible

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, connect

I'm trying to create a program that monitors an IRC server, and I'm having trouble even with the basics of connecting. I'm working on a linux cluster, at my school.

I simply don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code, copied almost verbatim from TCP IP Sockets in C, Chapter 2.

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {

      char *servName = "irc.freenode.net";
      in_port_t servPort = 6667;

      //Start populating server information into a sockaddr
      struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
           memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));

           //To get the IP address of irc.freenode.net
               //Using gethostbyname
           char servIP[16];
           struct hostent *hent;
           hent = gethostbyname(servName);
           inet_ntop(AF_INET, (void *)hent->h_addr_list[0],servIP,16);         

           //Convert the IP address's endianness
           int rtnVal = inet_pton(AF_INET, servIP, &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
           if(rtnVal <= 0)
                dieMsg("inet fail",rtnVal);

           servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);
           servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
           printf("%s\n",servIP);
      //End server information

      //Open a socket to use
      int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);          
      if(sock<0)
           dieMsg("sock fail",sock);

      //Connect using the sock, and the populated sockaddr struct.
      if(connect(sock,(struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr))<0);
      {
           dieMsg("con fail",-1);
      }

      return 0;
 }
```

`dieMsg` is a function that takes a string and an int, prints them, and then exits.

The output of this code is

```
89.16.176.16
con fail -1
```

Alternatively, I've also used the `addrinfo` struct, to no avail:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    

     char *servHostc = "irc.freenode.net";
     char *servPortc = "6667";

     struct addrinfo addrCriteria;
     memset(&addrCriteria, 0, sizeof(addrCriteria));
     addrCriteria.ai_family = AF_INET;
     addrCriteria.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
     addrCriteria.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

     struct addrinfo *servAddr;
     int rtnVal = getaddrinfo(servHostc,servPortc, &addrCriteria, &servAddr);
     if(rtnVal != 0)
          dieMsg("getaddrinfo() connect fail", rtnVal);

     int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

     if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr) < 0))
     {
          free(servAddr);
          dieMsg("Connect failed",-1);
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Telnet works for both addresses, so it's not my internet connection.

```
$ telnet irc.freenode.net 6667
Trying 128.237.157.136...
Connected to irc.freenode.net (128.237.157.136).
Escape character is '^]'.
:hubbard.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname...
:hubbard.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Checking Ident
:hubbard.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Found your hostname
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
$ telnet 89.16.176.16 6667
Trying 89.16.176.16...
Connected to wolfe.freenode.net (89.16.176.16).
Escape character is '^]'.
:wolfe.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname...
:wolfe.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Checking Ident
:wolfe.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Found your hostname
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
```

I usually hate asking questions, so this is my last resort. If anyone can please please shed some light on my predicament, I will be so grateful.

Comment: Your diemsg() function is a waste of time. There is an error code in errno, and an existing function perror() that will turn it into an error message. Without that information it is impossible for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: You don't happen to have a firewall stopping you?

Comment: The first code snippet would not compile - `free(servAddr)` when `servAddr` is not a pointer?

Comment: @EJP, thanks for the response. I didn't realize that I could use the perror() message. I'll code that, and come back with the error info.

Comment: @larsw, I assume not; but, to be honest, I don't know if I do or don't, since I am not the admin of the clusters. Is there a way I can check manually?

Comment: @HardBoot Telnet from the same machine where you run your compiled program? I've just tried to compile and run your first snippet (after correcting `free(servAddr)`) - it connected without problems.

Comment: @CodePainters, Good point; I must have flubbed the copy/paste when I added the `addrinfo` version.

Comment: @CodePainters, really? Well, that gives me some confidence. But, the thing is I am telnetting from the same machine as my compilation.

Comment: Your first version works for me (after removing spurious trailing `;` in its connect call), second does not. Note that in the connect call of the 2nd you have `sizeof(servAddr) < 0))` which should be `sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)`.  But that is not all that is stopping it from working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  if(connect(sock,(struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr))<0);
  {
       dieMsg("con fail",-1);
  }
```

`;` at the end of `if`.

Comment: Still the connect() call works when I tried it (using `strace`) :)

Comment: @CodePainters: The problem is not the connect call, it's that regardless of whether connect succeeds, the `dieMsg()` call is *always* being triggered.  The semicolon `;` means the if statement is not executing anything, and the subsequent brackets are meaningless to the compiler

Comment: I can't believe it. I simply can't believe it.

Comment: Sure, I understand this code! I was just kidding at the fact, that in fact `connect()` call worked for me without problems, `strace` proved that connect returns 0. Of course, this comma at the end is a bug, no question!

Comment: This is exactly correct; actually, thanks to @EPJ's suggestion of using the perror(), and CodePainter's confirmation that it works, I was heading down the track to realizing that my connect was actually working. I can't believe I've been pulling my hair out for the past 4 hours, and it was this semicolon, hahaha.

Thank you so much, Banthar, and stalk overflow!

Comment: @HardBoot I suggest you leave Banthar's answer as accepted - he was the one to notice the semicolon, I assumed incorrectly, that `connect()` really fails for you ;) Sure, you can still upvote my answer if it is useful :)

Comment: @CodePainters, Whoops; I sillily thought SO would accept two answers. Obviously, still unfamiliar with it (if it wasn't evident by my reputation). I promise, though once I get 15 rep, I'll be sure to come back to upvote you.

Answer (score 1):

The second code sample is also buggy. The line:

```
 if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr) < 0))
```

Can you see? You are comparing `sizeof()` to zero, not the `connect()` result!
Also, you don't use the `servAddr` properly. Try replacing this line with (again, it works for me after the change):

```
 if(connect(sock, servAddr->ai_addr, servAddr->ai_addrlen) < 0)
```

Also note, that `servAddr` is in fact a linked list, see this sample: http://www.geekpage.jp/en/programming/linux-network/getaddrinfo-3.php

Also, I suggest you try using [Strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) - it's exceptionally useful when you want to check quickly what's going on.

**Edit:** I can see one more bug - `free()` should be called regardless of `connect()` result, you are leaking memory here. And again, a tool hint: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: My god. Two different if statement errors... no wonder nothing was working! I probably wouldn't have realized it, either. Thanks for the extra help!